# mass mail/load test/newsletter from Domino/Lotus Notes system

Tags: load-testing, lotus-notes, ibm-domino

I need to generate a few thousand mails in Lotus Notes (with attachment) in order to test an extension to the Domino router I wrote.

How can I do that? It may not be mails that are send into Domino via SMTP because I need to test Notes routing and real notes mails.

Does someone have a guide or macro or agent etc. that goes in a Lotus Notes intallation and autoamtes the process of creating tons of mails?

Comment: Can some one add the tag "lotusnotes"?

Answer (score 2):

This article on the DominoPower.com site could be helpful: [Different ways to programmatically create an email message](http://www.dominopower.com/issues/issue200411/00001419001.html).

Basically the author describes how to use `ShellExecute` in order to open "mailto:" links.

Answer (score 0):

Server.Load in standart Domino Administrator package.